# <canvas> javascript game frameworks

Tags: javascript, frameworks, canvas

Do you know any except [GameJS](http://ajaxian.com/archives/gamejs-canvas-game-library), which actualy isn't working on my pc, in FF3.5 i try to start attached jetris demo and i see nothing, even firebug console is clear.

I tried something called GameQuery, looks nice but it's working on pure DOM, im interested in CANVAS.

Comment: you think is better to dev game in DOM than in Canvas?

Answer (score 0):

Its fairly basic but what about http://mccormick.cx/projects/jsGameSoup/